# $X_{1},...,X_{n}$ ~ $Ber(p)$ what can I say about $\exp(\lambda X_{1}),...,\exp(\lambda X_{n})$

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, random-variables, independence

Let $X_{1},...,X_{n}$ ~ $Ber(p)$ be independent, and $\lambda > 0$. What can I say about $\exp(\lambda X_{1}),...,\exp(\lambda X_{n})$ with respect to $\mathbb E[\exp(\lambda X_{i})]$?

Well because $f_{\lambda }(x):=e^{\lambda x}$ is a continuous random variable, $(f_{\lambda }(X_{i}))_{i=1,...,n}$ are independent and identically distributed.

I assume $\exp(\lambda X_{i})$ will be bernoulli distributed but I fail to find a way to determine the Bernoulli coefficients, and how to prove these. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Well because $f_{\lambda }(x):=e^{\lambda x}$ is a continuous random variable, $(f_{\lambda }(X_{i}))_{i=1,...,n}$ are independent and identically distributed.

This is not true. Since $X_k$ are all discrete, then so is $\exp(\lambda X_k)$. Using the rule of discrete expectation, we can say that
$$E(\exp(\lambda X)) = \sum_{x \in \lbrace 0,1 \rbrace } \Pr(X=x) \exp(\lambda x)  = \Pr(X=0)\exp(\lambda (0)) + \Pr(X=1)\exp(\lambda (1))$$
Since $\Pr(X=0) = 1-p$ and $\Pr(X=1) = p$, we get
$$E(\exp(\lambda X)) = 1-p+ p\exp(\lambda )$$

Comment: Why is $(f_{\lambda}(X_{i}))_{i=1,...n}$ not i.i.d.?

Comment: @SABOY i did not say it is not i.i.d .. i said it is not true meaning that it is not a continuous random variable. It is a discrete random variable.

Comment: Apologies, misunderstanding

Comment: no worries :) @SABOY

Answer (score 1):

Guide:

If $X_i=0$, we have $\exp(\lambda X_i)=1$, this happens with probability $1-p$.

What happens to $\exp(\lambda X_i)$ if $X_i=1$? what is the corresponding probability.

Now use the definition of expectation to compute the desired quantity.

Comment: If $X_{i}=1$ then $\exp(\lambda X_{i})=\exp(\lambda)$ The corresponding probability would be $0$ would it not, unless $\lambda = 0$?

Comment: the correponding probability should be $p$.

Comment: So we've got $P(\exp(\lambda X_{i})=\exp(\lambda))=p$ while $P(\exp(\lambda X_{i})=1)=1-p$, so a kind of Bernoulli distribution between two values $\exp(\lambda)$ and $1$?

Comment: It is a discrete distribution that only takes two values.